# Grid lines in secondary y axis in Power Bi

Tags: r, plot, powerbi

I am using a line and clustered column chart in Power Bi in which I have a dual y-axis. I need grid lines for the secondary y-axis, i.e. the y-axis with the line value.

In Power Bi, for the primary y-axis we can just turn on the grid lines option to get the grid lines, but there's no option for the secondary y-axis. Is there any R script or any internal Power Bi option to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get the question.

PowerBI creates gridlines automatically and they are a different thing than the Y axis labels.

So I think you most likely want, is to turn off primary Y axis labels and keep secondary Y-axis labels on? First, why would you do that? It' going to be confusing for the end users.

Secondly, PowerBI does not support it natively (more specifically, I am not aware of that functionality), but there might be a workaround using different colors:

Set primary Y axis label to white (or same as your background) and secondary Y-axis label to black.
The output might look like this:

[image]

There are custom R visuals available, so I suppose you could write some code, but is it really worth it?

Comment: I wanr to show the labels in the primary y axis but the gridlines should belong to the secondary values and not the primary ones

Comment: @Nit2702 Oh, I see. In that case, you want just to switch positions, ie set Position of primary Y-axis to right and position of secondary Y-axis to left.

Comment: No that does not change my grid positions it still takes the gridlines from the y axis (column) part

Comment: @Nit2702 In that case, I don't think, that you can bound gridlines to secondary Y-axis. You can turn "align zeroes" and it should be around the same position...
Another workaround might be for you to create two overlaying visuals, but I would not recommend that.